# Adding Maven Dependencies to XML with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

I'm currently watching a tutorial on adding a Maven dependency to a pom.xml file and it does not appear to be working as it should. I downloaded the external jar file to the library and in the video his xml code is automatically updated with the dependency. Since mine was not automatically updated I tried to generate a dependency. My artifact did not show up in the artifact list. So, I tried to manually enter in the following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This created red squiggly lines under the dependency tags with an error message of, "Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'".

If someone could walk me through step by step how I can get this to work I would it appreciate it very much.

Comment: You put it in the wrong place if you get that error. What does the Maven command-line say?

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the Maven command line. I'm totally new to this.

Comment: You go to the directory, and you type 'mvn'. It's essential to be familiar with this if you're working with a Maven project; depending on the IDE for everything you are unlikely to succeed. In any case, you should read:  https://maven.apache.org/pom.html for help in seeing what you did wrong.

Comment: check your `pom.xml` format, you may missed a opening or closing tag.

Comment: @bmargulies I don't quite understand what you're saying but I just installed Apache Maven by setting the environment variable because I wasn't getting anything when I typed "mvn" or "mvn -v" into the command prompt. Now when I type "mvn -v" it gives me the correct result but when I type in "mvn" I get a bunch of errors like, "build failure" and "no goals have been specified for this build".

Comment: Sound's like you are in the wrong directory. You need to be in the directory with the pom.xml, and probably type `mvn compile`

Comment: Okay I did that but I'm getting another error saying, "malformed POM...unrecognized tag: dependency" and such.

Comment: Okay I did it on an earlier file I made and it seems to be working now. For reference, this project was created using archetypes and the code above wasn't in the xml. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1) After setting environment variable JAVA_HOME, install Apache Maven here, https://maven.apache.org/install.html.

2) If you have already created a new project in Intellij IDEA, open the command prompt and access the directory of the pom.xml file (example type: "cd C:\Users\Kyle\IdeaProjects\MavenDemo").

3) Type: mvn compile

4) In Intellij type alt+insert to generate a dependency. If you have downloaded it correctly from the Maven repository it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

mvn compile //Inside project folder